# Creating dictionary with g2p-seq2seq: ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I ran this command:

```
g2p-seq2seq --interactive --model_dir g2p-seq2seq-cmudict
```

But I got this error: :(

> /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/**init**.py:36: FutureWarning:
>   Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to
>   `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as
>   `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.   from ._conv import
>   register_converters as _register_converters Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "/usr/bin/g2p-seq2seq", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('g2p-seq2seq==6.1.3a0', 'console_scripts', 'g2p-seq2seq')()   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2p_seq2seq-6.1.3a0-py2.7.egg/g2p_seq2seq/app.py",
>   line 107, in main
>       params.hparams = g2p_trainer_utils.load_params(FLAGS.model_dir)   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/g2p_seq2seq-6.1.3a0-py2.7.egg/g2p_seq2seq/g2p_trainer_utils.py",
>   line 210, in load_params
>       model_params = json.load(open(params_file_path))   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 290, in load
>       **kw)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 338, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
>       raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded") ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Please help T_T

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the last version of g2p-seq2seq (6.2.0a0) and the previous version of tensor2tensor=1.5.7 (the issue with upgrading to new versions of t2t higher 1.6.0 is still not solved).
Also, you need to download [the latest pre-trained model](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/G2P%20Models/g2p-seq2seq-model-6.2-cmudict-nostress.tar.gz/download).